# ClojureScript - name goog is not defined in the externs

Tags: clojure, electron, clojurescript, google-closure-compiler

I've been trying Electron with ClojureScript with this [template](https://github.com/Gonzih/cljs-electron) and I've decided to upgrade Clojure and ClojureScript (to get performance updates from CLJS 1.10.x), however, I've got some warnings and electron app doesn't work after the upgrade.

I get these errors:

```
WARNING: resources/public/js/ui-release-out/inferred_externs.js:19: WARNING - name goog is not defined in the externs.
goog.isArrayLike;
^^^^

Apr 08, 2018 5:14:05 PM com.google.javascript.jscomp.LoggerErrorManager printSummary
WARNING: 0 error(s), 1 warning(s)
Successfully compiled ["resources/public/js/ui-core.js"] in 12.076 seconds.
Compiling ClojureScript...
Compiling ["resources/main.js"] from ["electron_src"]...
Apr 08, 2018 5:14:17 PM com.google.javascript.jscomp.LoggerErrorManager println
WARNING: resources/public/js/electron-release/inferred_externs.js:5: WARNING - name goog is not defined in the externs.
goog.isArrayLike;
^^^^

Apr 08, 2018 5:14:17 PM com.google.javascript.jscomp.LoggerErrorManager printSummary
WARNING: 0 error(s), 1 warning(s)
Successfully compiled ["resources/main.js"] in 8.182 seconds.
```

If I downgrade the ClojureScript dependency to `1.9.542`, everything works fine.
I get this error with `1.9.946` as well.

Everything works fine in the development build, though.

It seems that it might be related to this ticket https://dev.clojure.org/jira/browse/CLJS-2392

You can reproduce it cloning this repo https://github.com/Alexx-G/cljs-electron and be running `lein do clean, cljsbuild once frontend-release, cljsbuild once electron-release`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, there were 2 problems:
- that warning related to `goog` (which didn't affect the build itself)
- for some reasons `js/process` was different from `(js/require "process")`

Providing externs files and accessing process via `js/require` solved warnings and runtime problem.

The version with fixed problems and latest clj and cljs libraries is here https://github.com/Alexx-G/cljs-electron

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend the first thing you do is upgrade all of your libraries.  I'm currently set with

```
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.9.0"]
                 [org.clojure/clojurescript "1.10.238"]
                 [org.clojure/core.async "0.4.474"]]

  :plugins [[lein-cljsbuild "1.1.7" :exclusions [[org.clojure/clojure]]]
            [lein-doo "0.1.10"]
            [lein-figwheel "0.5.15"]]
```

on my current project.

Comment: P.S. The current project (still in progress) can be seen at git@github.com:cloojure/fred.git

Comment: I did something wrong today and got a similar error to yours "goog not found" or something.  I kept pounding until it works now.  Notice the 2 ways of including native JS, `dino.js` using externs and `wilma.js` using `goog.provide('xxx')`.

Comment: Apparently, that warning didn't affect the build at all. After I enabled `pretty-print` and `pseudo-names` I saw that the problem was in `js/process` for some reasons... Posted the answer.
Thanks for your feedback.